# Tomcat6 throws java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, symfony, tomcat6

I have a Symfony application running on a vagrant VM with CentOS 6 and hosted on Apache Tomcat 6. When I try to access the application, I get a `Secure Connection Failed` error. The tomcat logs show this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.io.EOFException
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.<clinit>(ZoneInfoFile.java:251)
    (....more lines)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.load(ZoneInfoFile.java:294)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.access$000(ZoneInfoFile.java:61)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:258)
    ... 37 more
```

This started happening seemingly out of nowhere, with no apparent triggers. Following various posts on SO, I deleted the following directories:

```
${CATALINA_HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost/cas
${CATALINA_HOME}/work/Catalina
${CATALINA_HOME}/temp
${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/cas
/var/cache/tomcat6/temp
/var/cache/tomcat6/work
```

where 'cas' is the name of the application. I restarted the tomcat6 service using `sudo service tomcat6 restart` and the command seems to run successfully. But when I run 'sudo service tomcat6 status', I get 
`PID file exists, but process is not running [FAILED]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like a Java installation problem. Reinstall it.

Comment: I reinstalled java-1.7.0 and jre-1.7.0 using 'yum remove' and 'yum install', but it made no difference. I also tried deleting tomcat6.pid and restarting tomcat6 service, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by running `yum update`. It showed that there are duplicated packages. Following [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/801967/cant-update-server-with-yum-duplicates-error) post, I deleted the duplicated packages and ran `yum distro-sync`. Then, tomcat6 was able to start successfully.